# How can I traverse a file system with a generator?

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, generator, yield

I'm trying to create a utility class for traversing all the files in a directory, including those within subdirectories and sub-subdirectories. I tried to use a generator because generators are cool; however, I hit a snag.

```
def grab_files(directory):
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, name)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            yield grab_files(full_path)
        elif os.path.isfile(full_path):
            yield full_path
        else:
            print('Unidentified name %s. It could be a symbolic link' % full_path)
```

When the generator reaches a directory, it simply yields the memory location of the new generator; it doesn't give me the contents of the directory.

#### How can I make the generator yield the contents of the directory instead of a new generator?

If there's already a simple library function to recursively list all the files in a directory structure, tell me about it. I don't intend to replicate a library function.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel when you can use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
```

os.walk is a generator that yields the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up

Comment: But then again, by reinventing the wheel we could `os.cycle` rather than `os.walk`...

Comment: I think it's a joke... "reinventing the wheel"?  Walking vs. cycling?  Pretty good.. :)

Comment: Yes, Ned, a joke. The suggestion to os.walk() is the way-to-go, unless one is merely trying to learn about generators and uses directory traversal as a practical exercise for it.

Comment: @Ned: I literally just facepalmed.

Comment: os.walk might be a generator, but its granularity is a directory level and the files it returns is a list.  If you have a directory with millions of files in it, good luck using os.walk. At least this is true in 2.7.

Comment: In addition to what woot pointed out, `os.walk` also sorts symbolic links into either the directory or file list based on the files they point to. This is fine much of the time, but not if you are trying to operate on the links instead of the linked-to files.

Comment: @woot - that's exactly why I'm here - I'm trying to split my million files into subdirectories (git object style), but os.listing is taking forever...

Comment: @iAdjunct Look at using scandir. https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir for python 2.x, else it is built in in python 3.x I think.

Comment: Yes, scandir is built into 3 and returns an iterator. listdir still returns a list.

Comment: `walk()` internally uses `listdir()` so that loses the advantages of using a generator like `walk()`in the first place. Just use `scandir()`. Source: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/29f0836c0456/Lib/os.py#l276

Comment: To be clear, what I said above only applies to Python 2 and versions of Python 3 before 3.5. The maintained versions of Python no longer have that issue with `walk()`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/64fc105b2d2faaeadd1026d2417b83915af6622f/Lib/os.py#L357

Answer (score 16):

As of Python 3.4, you can use the `glob()` method from the built-in pathlib module:

```
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('.')
list(p.glob('**/*'))    # lists all files recursively
```

Comment: Just to confirm, `type(p.glob('**/*'))` indeed returns `generator`.

Answer (score 15):

I agree with the os.walk solution

For pure pedantic purpose, try iterate over the generator object, instead of returning it directly:

```
def grab_files(directory):
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, name)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            for entry in grab_files(full_path):
                yield entry
        elif os.path.isfile(full_path):
            yield full_path
        else:
            print('Unidentified name %s. It could be a symbolic link' % full_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I figured out this solution about five minutes after I had posted the question. XD

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Python 3.4, you can use the [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
In [48]: def alliter(p):
   ....:     yield p
   ....:     for sub in p.iterdir():
   ....:         if sub.is_dir():
   ....:             yield from alliter(sub)
   ....:         else:
   ....:             yield sub
   ....:             

In [49]: g = alliter(pathlib.Path("."))                                                                                                                                                              

In [50]: [next(g) for _ in range(10)]
Out[50]: 
[PosixPath('.'),
 PosixPath('.pypirc'),
 PosixPath('.python_history'),
 PosixPath('lshw'),
 PosixPath('.gstreamer-0.10'),
 PosixPath('.gstreamer-0.10/registry.x86_64.bin'),
 PosixPath('.gconf'),
 PosixPath('.gconf/apps'),
 PosixPath('.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal'),
 PosixPath('.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/%gconf.xml')]
```

This is essential the object-oriented version of [sjthebats answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698711/974555). 
Note that the [Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) `**` pattern returns only directories!

Comment: For people dealing with many files in directories, I believe this is the only truly iterative solution on this answer and possibly the only high-level way in the python(3) standard library. It should probably be added as an option to `iterdir()`.

Comment: @KobeJohn Isn't `yield from alliter(sub)` within a generator `alliter` rather recursive than iterative?

Comment: You are right. What I mean is that it gives you results without first doing a full stat on all the files in a directory. So even when you have a large number of files it can generate results immediately.

Answer (score 2):

[`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) is a "function returns directory entries along with file attribute information, giving better performance [than `os.listdir()`] for many common use cases." It's an iterator that does not use `os.listdir()` interally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py/2.2). Unfortunately the author's website is no longer around, but you can still download the code from PyPI. This library is a wrapper around path functions in the `os` module.

`path.py` provides a `walkfiles()` method which returns a generator iterating recursively over all files in the directory:

```
>>> from path import path
>>> print path.walkfiles.__doc__
 D.walkfiles() -> iterator over files in D, recursively.

        The optional argument, pattern, limits the results to files
        with names that match the pattern.  For example,
        mydir.walkfiles('*.tmp') yields only files with the .tmp
        extension.

>>> p = path('/tmp')
>>> p.walkfiles()
<generator object walkfiles at 0x8ca75a4>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

addendum to the answer of gerrit. I wanted to make something more flexible.

list all files in `pth` matching a given `pattern`, can also list dirs if `only_file` is `False`

```
from pathlib import Path

def walk(pth=Path('.'), pattern='*', only_file=True) :
    """ list all files in pth matching a given pattern, can also list dirs if only_file is False """
    if pth.match(pattern) and not (only_file and pth.is_dir()) :
        yield pth
    for sub in pth.iterdir():
        if sub.is_dir():
            yield from walk(sub, pattern, only_file)
        else:
            if sub.match(pattern) :
                yield sub
```